# FreeTDS mssql_connect not working

Tags: php, sql-server, ubuntu, freetds, unixodbc

I have a UBUNTU LAMP setup. All the necessary extensions installed

`php5-odbc`
`php5-mssql`
`FREETDS`
`unixODBC`

From CLI i have tested my connection to the DB using `isql` and `tsql` and both are connecting and working perfectly.

Here is my `freetds.conf`:

```
    ....
    # A typical Microsoft server
[TS]
        host = 10.32.6.52
        port = 1433
        tds version = 8.0
        client charset = UTF-8
```

Here is my odbc.ini

```
[TS]
Description = "XXXXXXX"
Driver = /usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
Server = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Port = 1433
Database = XX_X_XX_XXXXX
Trace = No
TDS_Version = 8.0
[Default]
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
```

Here is my odbcinst.ini

```
[FreeTDS]
Description = FreeTDS
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
FileUsage = 1
CPTimeout =
CPResuse  =
client charset = utf-8
UsageCount = 1
```

And here is my php

```
<?php

putenv("TDSVER=80");
putenv("FREETDSCONF=/etc/freetds/freetds.conf");
putenv("ODBCSYSINI=/etc/odbcinst.ini");
putenv("ODBCINI=/etc/odbc.ini");


$myServer = "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX";
$username = "XXXXX";
$password = "XXXXX";
$database = "XXXXX";

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $username, $password)
  or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer");

//select a database to work with
$selected = mssql_select_db($database, $dbhandle)
  or die("Couldn't open database $myDB");

//declare the SQL statement that will query the database
$query = "SELECT title from project where id = 8 ";

//execute the SQL query and return records
$result = mssql_query($query);

$numRows = mssql_num_rows($result);
echo "<h1>" . $numRows . " Row" . ($numRows == 1 ? "" : "s") . " Returned </h1>";

//display the results
while($row = mssql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo "<li>" . $row["title"] . "</li>";
}
//close the connection
mssql_close($dbhandle);
?>
```

Like i said from CLI i can connect to the SQL server, but from php it doesnt work. I have tried all the suggestions i could find but nothing is working for me.

Also for reference here is my Apache Error Log:

```
[Tue Jun 09 08:32:41.931108 2015] [:error] [pid 21435] [client 10.32.6.65:54994] PHP Warning:  mssql_connect(): Unable to connect to server: XXXXXXXX in /var/www/html/test/sqltest.php on line 15
[Tue Jun 09 08:32:41.931124 2015] [:error] [pid 21435] [client 10.32.6.65:54994] PHP Stack trace:
[Tue Jun 09 08:32:41.931134 2015] [:error] [pid 21435] [client 10.32.6.65:54994] PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/html/test/sqltest.php:0
[Tue Jun 09 08:32:41.931142 2015] [:error] [pid 21435] [client 10.32.6.65:54994] PHP   2. mssql_connect() /var/www/html/test/sqltest.php:15
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue and resolved it. I enabled the Freetds.log by uncommenting the log file location in `/etc/freetds/freetds.conf`

Here is the log file extract

```
config.c:303:[XXXXXXXXX] not found.
config.c:367:... $FREETDS not set.  Trying $HOME.
config.c:293:Could not open '/var/www/.freetds.conf' ((.freetds.conf)).
config.c:297:Found conf file '/usr/local/etc/freetds.conf' (default).
config.c:483:Looking for section global.
config.c:542:   Found section global.
config.c:545:Got a match.
config.c:567:   text size = '64512'
config.c:542:   Found section egserver50.
config.c:542:   Found section egserver70.
config.c:556:   Reached EOF
config.c:483:Looking for section XXXXXXXXXXXX.
config.c:542:   Found section global.
config.c:542:   Found section egserver50.
config.c:542:   Found section egserver70.
config.c:556:   Reached EOF
config.c:303:[XXXXXXXXXXXX] not found.
config.c:208:Failed in reading conf file.  Trying interface files.
config.c:1042:Looking for server XXXXXXXXXXX....
```

So basically it was looking for my servername in the freetds.conf files. but i didnt specify it. the connection information was listed in the config file as `[TS]` i changed my php information to look for `[TS]` and the all of a sudden it worked

```
$myServer = "TS";
$username = "XXXXX";
$password = "XXXXX";
$database = "XXXXX";
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to post this in the event it helps anyone else who may be experiencing the same issue:

What ended up working for me: Changing the `$host` value in my `PHP` connection string to the reference name of the server I was trying to connect to,as I specified it in `freetds.conf` and `.odbc.ini`, instead of the actual `IP` address.

Thank you @Stroes for pointing me in the right direction. This issue literally almost brought me to tears after over a week of reading articles and troubleshooting.